# Do the mafia and dark fantasy genres work well together?

Tags: creative-writing, romance, horror, dark-fantasy

I've been writing a book for two years now, and it feels like the plot could work better if I include a mafia, like a lot of things would come together if I include that my male lead is the underboss of a mob. However, it also has fantasy elements like hell and demons etc. This hell is unique in some ways.

Initially, I wanted to focus on this uniqueness, but now the plot demands to focus on the chase aspect, which is that the male lead has to find the protagonist and kill them. But obviously they fall in love because this is a heavy romance I'm writing.

Yesterday I explained a watered-down version of my plot to someone on Omegle and they told me that beings from hell in the Mafia do not work well. That dark fantasy and mobs don't go well together. I actually am writing an urban fantasy, but I guess you could call it dark fantasy too. There is another side couple too, who had a very tragic past life that I want to include.

What should I do? Should I proceed with the plot, keeping the mob part, or should I make another universe (though I would like it to be realistic and based on the real world)? Also, remember it's a serious [mlm](https://www.lgbtqnation.com/2022/06/mlm-pride-flag/) romance, no corny stuff is included. It has some horror stuff too, like monsters etc. Should I make it horror?

Comment: The [Hollows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollows_(series)) series by Kim Harrison is an urban fantasy that basically has all this. The second book has a vampire that's basically a mob boss, and demons are heavily involved in the plot (though not as members of the mob; they're more like tactical weapons you can put on contract).

Comment: Best I can gather is that the Mafia, as many Americans understand it, is very associated with the Catholic Faith, which has some associations with fighting Demons and Demonic entities (they are the go to sect for real life exorcism sof demons possession in Christianity to this day).  However "the Mafia opposes it because the Catholic church opposes it" logic breaks because the Mafia does regularly engage in killing people, something the Catholic Church has been known frown upon from time to time (understatement).  To say nothing about the other commandments the mafia like to break.

Answer (score 1):

Mafia and dark fantasy seems like an interesting and a beautiful realm of it's own. For some reason, I am reminded of Batman, Resident Evil and Maybe Assassin's Creed Syndicate themes. Your story looks like an original combination that could open doors for a new genre or maybe stand between a few.

Mafia world is very casual, materialistic and real, but adding demons, monsters and hell couldn't be more attracting and even meaningful, since the Mafia is all about right and wrong, kill or be killed. Romance can be distracting but you can allude to it a little and cover sexuality a bit.

This can work as a video game too.

Comment: Re: video games. "The Darkness" (2007) and its sequel are specifically about a NY mafia protagonist with Demon powers. Based, IIRC, on a comic book/graphic novel (?).

Answer (score 1):

If you write it well without sounding like it was an unprepared inclusion, I don't see any problem.

History is its own fiction, its world. I write completely random stories, from baker bards who summon bread elementals to a battle between cats and dogs, where doves clash to acquire global domination.

The dark fantasy theme fits well with the mafia, bringing the sense of a hidden group that may be one of the causes of the situation in which that world finds itself. Because it is a tense atmosphere, it is possible to deal with heavier issues involving the mafia.

I trust you can do something good, after all, there is a manga that surprised me a lot called *Dandadan*, which involves occultism, ghosts, aliens, espers, and a drama of a mono-ball guy.

One other manga that I heard with a theme of an underground mafia is called *Ayashimon*.

Answer (score 0):

I have certainly read urban fantasy with organized crime.

Something to consider is how the magic affects the crime.  It doesn't have to, but it could.  Do junior Mafia members ever curse their superiors?  Do they curse those who don't pay their protection?  Do they divine who attacked a store that paid its protection money?

One possibility is calling it by a different name.  Possibly the magic in the world changed it subtly.